# verify signature with public key fail python hmac

Tags: python, hmac

```
    Publickey = '''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCVAMXVTMIuttHcP1kvSk9V39S7
    BqDbY+LC9JfwMzyoubo3fdsqBf4EmB1PfBUigcOL5YBqMKGEE6xmVw6SXCTH4JwX
    dqJ4IRiXf76YMt6PB0dMzu/qCmhaGFGkqT6vJM0hHyEbtS/P3FR9ZU+eaOvynLWb
    FvXTzIoctZM1IvDrCwIDAQAB
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----'''

    public_key_encoded = Publickey[26:-25].replace('\n', '')
    public_key_der = base64.b64decode(public_key_encoded)

    WebhookSignature = "VtniwOFAi4oBKFnvHhY6UZ+wPARf7+yWVbE61Hc7JVdRgqKJ40Yk9k5Gb2Y0S0VLUYOOOhUNUsD7R8GDEr6WH84sAEf8bXa1xYMiyjgeGleTg1MxRJCtrHcxMeMCEXPWmKTeLhn6O+cdvDGq4ZpcTTiQnEvk5xHPcxFrBT637zg="
    WebhookTimestamp = 1611232922428
    WebhookNonce = "5RhaTrZPhknNv0kDSA2UQ67cPMVNS4sA"
    event_body = {"bizType":"PAY","data":"{\"merchantTradeNo\":\"9825382937292\",\"totalFee\":0.88000000,\"transactTime\":1619508939664,\"currency\":\"EUR\",\"commission\":0,\"openUserId\":\"1211HS10K81f4273ac031\",\"productType\":\"Food\",\"productName\":\"Ice Cream\",\"tradeType\":\"WEB\",\"transactionId\":\"M_R_282737362839373\"}","bizId":29383937493038367292,"bizStatus":"PAY_SUCCESS"}
    payload_to_sign = str(WebhookTimestamp) + "\n" + WebhookNonce + "\n" + json.dumps(event_body) + "\n"
    print(payload_to_sign)
    decodeSignature = base64.b64decode(WebhookSignature)

    hmac_code = hmac.new(public_key_der, payload_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
    final_hash = hmac_code.digest()
    print(hmac.compare_digest(final_hash, decodeSignature))
```

I am trying to validate webhook with python. After hashing payload with public key, the result is not same as the signature.

Comment: java code
`// input: pubKeyStr, decodedSignature, payload
    PEMParser pubParser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(pubKeyStr))
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo pubKeyObj = (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) pubParser.readObject();
    AsymmetricKeyParameter pubKey = PublicKeyFactory.createKey(pubKeyObj);

    byte[] payloadBytes = payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    RSADigestSigner verifier = new RSADigestSigner(new SHA256Digest());
    verifier.init(false, pubKey);
    verifier.update(payloadBytes, 0, payloadBytes.length);

    return verifier.verifySignature(decodedSignature); `

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this is
cannot using hmac for Asymmetric-key use crypto and openssl instead

```
key = crypto.load_publickey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open("public_cert_new.pem","rb").read())
x509 = crypto.X509()
x509.set_pubkey(key)

crypto.verify(x509, base64.b64decode(WebhookSignature), payload_to_sign, 'sha256')
```